# Adding arrays to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, arraylist

I'm trying to produce a kind of lucky dip lotto number generator. At the moment, the code will produce the desired results but I'd really like to have the arrays in an arraylist. Here's my code so far:

Ticket Class:

```
public class Ticket
{
    private int numberOfLines;

    public void displayTicket(int numberOfLines)
    {
        Numbers numbersClass = new Numbers();

        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("**           Lotto Ticket            **");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("**                                   **");

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            numbersClass.populateArray();
            numbersClass.ticket();
        }

        System.out.println("**                                   **");
        System.out.println("***************************************");

    }
}
```

Numbers Class:

```
public class Numbers
{
    // Fields
    private int[] numberLine;
    private int randomNumber;
    private Random randomGen;


    // Constructor : Initialise number array
    public Numbers()
    {
        numberLine = new int[6];
        randomNumber = 0;
        randomGen = new Random();
    }

    // Method : Generate 6 random numbers in a range 1 to 49
     public void populateArray()
    {
        List<Integer> pool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; ++i)
        {
            pool.add(i + 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            randomNumber = randomGen.nextInt(pool.size());
            numberLine[i] = pool.get(randomNumber);
            pool.remove(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    // Method : Sort 6 numbers in ascending order  
    private int[] sortArray()
    {
        Arrays.sort(numberLine);
        return numberLine;
    }

    // Method : Format and display 6 numbers to the screen  
    public void ticket()
    {
        System.out.print("**         ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberLine.length; i++) 
        {
            if (numberLine[i] < 10) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(numberLine[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("        **\n");
    }
 }
```

The Ticket class will get the numberOfLines from the user at runtime, then print out the first half of the lotto ticket and then use the Numbers class to generate and print the random numbers, format them, then print them to the screen and finally print the bottom of the ticket.

What I should do really, is have the arrays from the Numbers class be stored into an arraylist in the Ticket class and then format the lines and print them from the Ticket Class.

Question 1: How would I go about adding the random number lines (the arrays) into an arraylist in the Ticket class?

Question 2: How would I format the lines if they are in an arraylist?

Comment: Why this `pool` List? This doesn't make any sense to me. Just use `randomNumber`.

Comment: Its there because the populateArray() method must avoid duplicates, you cannot draw two 6's in the lotto, for example, so you can't have it on the lotto line either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a list of arrays, you need to declare the list as holding an array.

```
List<int[]> arrs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Once you have that, you will need to use two loops to display the sets of results. One to iterate over the arrays in the list and the one you have now to print the array of numbers.

Comment: Firstly, the reason that populateArray() is the way it is is because it must avoid duplicates, you cannot draw two 6's in the lotto, for example, so you can't have it on the lotto line either.

Second, the purpose of the question was to put the array _into_ an arraylist, not turn the arrays into arraylists.

Comment: @Arcadian: I have updated my answer to address your actual question. By including all of the extra code, it was unclear that your question was actually about making a list of arrays. In the future, please include the bare minimum amount of code to convey your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that should allow me to add the arrays to the list. How do I format them from in there in order to display them on the ticket?

Comment: @Arcadian: That depends on how you actually want it displayed. The easiest would be the process I described in my answer of adding a loop to wrap around the existing one in `ticket()`.